# Cast json list to List

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I must use a second variable to hold my JSON lists, and then loop on that variable (as below):

```
 var _tempEquipment = _data['OutgoingItems'];

  // Work team
  for (var i = 0; i < _tempEquipment.length; i++) {
    x.add(Text(
      _tempEquipment[I],
      style: _dataText,
    ));
  }
```

I would much rather do something like this, but can't get it to work:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < (_data['Equipment'] as List).length; i++) {
    x.add(Text(
      _data['Equipment'][i].toString(),
      style: _dataText,
    ));
  }
```

Anyone have a solution for me? Thanks!

Comment: can you share any kinda error you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for (var item in _data['Equipment']) {
    x.add(Text(
     item.toString(),
      style: _dataText,
    ));
  }
```

Or this:

```
data['Equipment'].forEach((item)=>x.add(Text('$item', style: _dataText)));
```

It would help if you add what data does data['Equipment'] holds. Based on the information provided, I would guess it is array of string or some type.

Comment: Yes, strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
_data['Equipment'].forEach((eqp) => x.add(eqp.toString(),style:_dataText,));
```